# Sort the category with custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I want to sort the category using custom field value. So when I type newcat as name, I can define the category from the value box.

The loop is like this

```
 <?php query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=10&cat=XXXXXX');   
 if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php $count = 0; ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And the custom field call by this code:

```
<?php $newcat = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newcat', true); ?>
<?php echo $newcat; ?>
```

How can I change the XXXX on the loop with the custom field code? Please help. I'm not smart on php. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure that I understand what you want to do.

Assuming that your custom field meta key is 'newcat', you may like to try to replace:

```
<?php query_posts ('ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=10&cat=XXXXXX');
```

with:

```
<?php query_posts ('meta_key=newcat&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC&ignore_sticky_posts=1&showposts=10');
```